# Unable to call non-static constructor from inside static main function

Tags: java, compiler-errors, static

```
public class Main {
    private JLabel lb = new JLabel();
    private JButton btn = new JButton();

    public class events extends JFrame{
        public events(){
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            btn = new JButton("Click for text");
            lb = new JLabel();

            add(btn);
            add(lb);

            event  e = new event();
            btn.addActionListener(e);

        }
        public static stConst() {

        }
    }

    public class event implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            lb.setText("Now there is text here.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        events gui = new events();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(300, 300);
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Ok so before you go yelling at me for my naming conventions let me say I know how bad my variable names are. I have been trying to figure out java.swing event handling and I finally found an example program that i thought might work but then it gave me the error "non-static variable cannot be referenced from static context". It give me the error on the line at the bottom where I call the constructor so I think the error has something to do with the "this" object used in the constructor or maybe for some reason it's not letting me call my non-static constructor from inside my static main function. How do I fix this?

Comment: So if you are aware of your naming conventions why not fix them? ;)

Comment: your class `event` doesn't implement the abstract methods of `ActionListener`

Comment: idk this is just like a really arbitrary example that im just using to help myself learn how to use event listeners

Comment: wait is there more i have to do than just writing "implemets ActionListener"?

Comment: Make your nested classes static classes. `public static class event`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As events is Non static inner class, it must need a reference of parent class to be initialized.

**Option 1:**

You can simply call the inner class constructor using below statement in static method:

```
events gui = new Main().new events();
```

**Option 2:**

Create a non static function (like init) and then create instance of events from that function. From static function create an instance of parent class and then call this non static function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.init();
}

public void init() {
    events gui = new events();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setSize(300, 300);
    gui.setVisible(true);

}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your inner classes, `event` and `events` aren't `static` - they belong to a specific instance of your `Main` class (or, in other words, each instance has it's own inner class). The `main` method **is** `static`, though, so you cannot refer to instance members (even if they are classes!) from it.

Changing the inner classes, along with the data members of `Main` they rely on, to `static` should solve the issue.

Comment: would it also fix the problem if i just took the inner classes and defined them outside of main? or would they have to be static outside as well?

Comment: @hyphxnated Top level classes are implicitly static - that would work as well